# Locationhandler does not return Location with Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, location

I've created a location tracker application who send the location of a mobile device to a database.

When I test the location with my old samsung device (without a SIM) the application works. He sends the locationmanager and sends it to the db.

But when I test the application with my newer device. A samsung Galaxy. The application does not work. **It can't calculate the location because he says 'GPSisenabled' is false and 'NetworkedEnabled' is also false..**

Here's my code to determine the location. Maybe someone has a answer to this strange thing, thanks

```
public Location getLocation() {
    try {

        ConfigurationManager();

        if (isGPSEnabled == false && isNetworkEnabled == false) {
            // no network provider is enabled
            return null;
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                location = null;
                Log.d("Network", "Network - GET LOCATION ");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                location = null;
                if (location == null) {
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled - GET LOCATION");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location;
}
```

Comment: Which version of Android os is installed on new Samsung Galaxy?

Answer (score 0):

You should use FusedLocationProviderApi for getting the current location as per android documentation. Read more here : [Getting the Last Known Location](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: I too was having some problems using old Location Provider Api for fetching last known location. It was getting results from network but GPS was returning null. Then I used the new FusedLocationApi , which worked well. 
I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Could you maybe share your code via pastebin? I'm trying the FusedLocationApi but does not work..

Comment: A good tutorial for FusedLocationAPI :- [Android Location API using Google Play Services](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/)